# Reference Request: video lecture on module theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

Is there a good online series of introductory video - lectures on module theory?

I really like the Abstract Algebra course by Benedict Gross, unfortunately he does not cover modules, hence I was wondering whether there might be something similar on the web (I haven't found anything yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you look through these channels in youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/user/ColumbiaMathDept

https://www.youtube.com/user/litsky/videos

http://www.youtube.com/user/TheCatsters

And here is a video I found on module theory by Litsky:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FD-WF7OQJM

Video lecture on module theory by James Cook: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt2YiTl_7bM